# Type mismatch when consuming WCF in InfoPath

Tags: c#, wcf, types, wsdl, infopath

I'm trying to consume my own WCF Service in InfoPath2007. When I add the data source, consuming the wsdl file works well, it displays all the Operations/Methods correctly but when i try to choose the one i want i get the following Error:

> InfoPath has encountered an error. The operation Failed. Type
>   mismatch.

my system.serviceModel in Web.config looks the following:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="basicBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="basicBehaviour" name="whoami.Service">
        <endpoint address="whoAmI" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="whoami.ISoapService">    </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

this is how my interface looks like

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://localhost:51703/Service.svc", Name = "whoami")]
public interface ISoapService
{
    [OperationContract(Name="whoAmI")]
    DataSet whoAmI();
}
```

And this is how i implemented the interface

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://localhost:51703/Service.svc")]
// replace the above with the following to get it working
//[ServiceBehavior]
public class Service : ISoapService
{

    public System.Data.DataSet whoAmI()
    {
        //create DataTable to look like the xml structure
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable("data");
        myTable.Columns.Add("name");
        myTable.Columns.Add("mail");
        myTable.Rows.Add("Example, Phil", "example.phil@mycompany.com");

        //create DataSet and store table in it
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet("whoami");
        myDataSet.Tables.Add(myTable);

        return myDataSet;
    }
}
```

I found out that if i use

> [ServiceBehavior]

instead of

> [ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://localhost:51703/Service.svc")]

the error will sometimes be displayed but i can continue anyhow. The problem is though that the targetNamespace in the wsdl is then set to "Tempuri.org".
what I also tried are different bindings for the endpoint like

- webHttpBinding
- wsHttpBinding

but i get the same error.

I hope somebody can help.

cheers!

phil